# /bin/sh: 1: ./configure: not found - dockerfile

Tags: apache, docker, docker-compose, ubuntu-16.04

I need to install Cosign filter for Apacher server.

I need to use this cosign-filter from [Confluence](https://www.wiki.ed.ac.uk/display/EASE/Building+Cosign+Filter+for+the+Apache+Webserver+from+Source), but when my installation hits ./configure it trow as error:

```
ERROR: Unknown instruction: --ENABLE-APACHE2=/PATH/TO/APACHE2/BIN/APXS
```

Then i found out this [installation](http://documentation.its.umich.edu/node/596) for cosign filter with github repository, and because I use `ubuntu16.04` in my Docker container I found it more useful, but in this installation I have a problem with `autoconf` so when he hits `RUN autoconf` it trows this error:

```
autoconf: error: no input file
ERROR: Service 'web' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c autoconf' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Second error will happen when he hits `RUN ./configure --enable-apache2= which apx` it will trow this error:

```
Step 19/35 : RUN ./configure --enable-apache2=`which apxs`
 ---> Running in 1e9f870df22f
/bin/sh: 1: ./configure: not found
ERROR: Service 'web' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c ./configure --enable-apache2=`which apxs`' returned a non-zero code: 127
```

Dockerfile configuration:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
FROM python:3.5
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN cat /etc/passwd
RUN cat /etc/group

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    apache2 \
    apache2-dev \
    libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3 \
    autoconf \
    libssl-dev
RUN apt-get install -y openssl
RUN mkdir /var/run/sshd

ENV APACHE_RUN_USER www-data
ENV APACHE_RUN_GROUP www-data
ENV APACHE_LOG_DIR /var/log/apache2
ENV APACHE_LOCK_DIR /var/lock/apache2
ENV APACHE_PID_FILE /var/run/apache2.pid

# The Umich IAM copy of Cosign includes Apache 2.4 support
RUN wget https://github.com/umich-iam/cosign/archive/master.tar.gz
RUN tar xfz master.tar.gz
RUN cd cosign-master
RUN autoconf
RUN ./configure --enable-apache2=`which apxs`
RUN make
RUN make isntall
RUN mkdir -p /var/cosign/filter
RUN chown www-data:www-data /var/cosign/filter

RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code
ADD requirements.txt /code/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
ADD . /code

EXPOSE 80


# Update the default apache site with the config we created.
COPY 000-default.conf /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf

RUN chown -R root:www-data /var/www
RUN chmod u+rwx,g+rx,o+rx /var/www
RUN find /var/www -type d -exec chmod u+rwx,g+rx,o+rx {} +
RUN find /var/www -type f -exec chmod u+rw,g+rw,o+r {} +

#essentially: CMD ["/usr/sbin/apachectl", "-D", "FOREGROUND"]
CMD ["/tmp/start.sh"]
```

So is there a way I can fix this so I can install and configure this filter, thanks.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Dockerd will run a new container for every `instruction` except `FROM` in `Dockerfile`, so

```
RUN cd cosign-master
RUN autoconf
RUN ./configure --enable-apache2=`which apxs`
```

three commands will be executed in three `standalone` containers, so `cd cosign-master` command can NOT change the `PWD` environment for next containers.
You can use the `absolute path` or execute the associated commands in ONE container, which means in ONE `instruction`.

```
RUN cd cosign-master \
    && autoconf \
    && ./configure --enable-apache2=`which apxs` \
    && make \
    && make install
```

PS:

1. should use one `instruction` to execute more commands to reduce the number of layers, because each `instruction` will generate a new layer.
2. should clean up the `intermediate` files or softwares to reduce the size of final image.

For examples:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
FROM python:3.5

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1 \
    APACHE_RUN_USER=www-data \
    APACHE_RUN_GROUP=www-data \
    APACHE_LOG_DIR=/var/log/apache2 \
    APACHE_LOCK_DIR=/var/lock/apache2 \
    APACHE_PID_FILE=/var/run/apache2.pid

RUN set -ex \
    && cat /etc/passwd \
    && cat /etc/group \
    && apt-get update \
    && export COMPILE_TOOLS="autoconf libssl-dev openssl" \
    && apt-get install -y \
               apache2 \
               apache2-dev \
               libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3 \
               ${COMPILE_TOOLS} \
    && wget https://github.com/umich-iam/cosign/archive/master.tar.gz -O /tmp/cosign-master.tar.gz \
    && tar xfz /tmp/cosign-master.tar.gz -C=/tmp \
    && cd /tmp/cosign-master \
    && autoconf \
    && ./configure --enable-apache2=$(which apxs) \
    && make \
    && make install \
    && mkdir -p /var/cosign/filter \
    && chown www-data:www-data /var/cosign/filter \
    && apt-get purge -y ${COMPILE_TOOLS} \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
              /tmp/cosign-master.tar.gz \
              /tmp/cosign-master/*

WORKDIR /code

# The Umich IAM copy of Cosign includes Apache 2.4 support
COPY requirements.txt /code/
COPY . /code
# Update the default apache site with the config we created.
COPY 000-default.conf /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf

RUN mkdir /var/run/sshd \
    && pip install -r requirements.txt \
    && chown -R root:www-data /var/www \
    && chmod u+rwx,g+rx,o+rx /var/www \
    && find /var/www -type d -exec chmod u+rwx,g+rx,o+rx {} + \
    && find /var/www -type f -exec chmod u+rw,g+rw,o+r {} +

EXPOSE 80

#essentially: CMD ["/usr/sbin/apachectl", "-D", "FOREGROUND"]
CMD ["/tmp/start.sh"]
```

This will:

1. reduce layers of your image from about `35` to just `9`!
2. reduce the size of your image immensely, maybe only `one third` of your origin image.
3. maybe a little difficult to read :)

Hope this helps!

Comment: it is strange how so many tutorials advocate separate `RUN` commands like here:  https://pythonspeed.com/articles/activate-conda-dockerfile/

Comment: The tutorial there says, "Each `RUN` is a new shell session"