# Docker can't find configure file

Tags: python, docker, protocol-buffers, dockerfile, configure

I'm creating a Dockerfile. I've included the unzipped [protobuf-3.3.0](https://github.com/google/protobuf/releases) folder for Python in the same directory as the Dockerfile. There is a binary named `configure` in the protobuf folder that totally works on my (non-Docker) host.

I have the following lines in my Dockerfile:

```
WORKDIR /protobuf-3.3.0
RUN ./configure && make && make install
```

However, this results in the following fatal error:

```
Step 4/13 : WORKDIR protobuf-3.3.0
 ---> 077ec08916d7
Removing intermediate container 50647f3aa6d7
Step 5/13 : RUN ./configure && make && make install
 ---> Running in 2d6f8446cdd9
/bin/sh: 1: ./configure: not found
```

Why?!? According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20632258/docker-change-directory-command), what I have in my Dockerfile is exactly right. I also tried the version [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44451696/bin-sh-1-configure-not-found-dockerfile), but the results were the same.

Comment: Show the whole Dockerfile

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you have in your current folder is called context. It is available to your docker container to copy and work with, but it doesn't mean it there in your container.

You need to copy it in your dockerfile

```
WORKDIR /protobuf-3.3.0
COPY ./protobuf-3.3.0 /protobuf-3.3.0
RUN ./configure && make && make install
```

`WORKDIR` only specifies what the current directory would be inside the container but doesn't copy that folder from context